# How do I add a value for a new field in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

My team added a new field in our DynamoDB and I need to add an integer for all entries that do not currently contain the field.

I've tried using the Update example [here](https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-partiql/), however I am getting a `ValidationException: Where clause does not contain a mandatory equality on all key attributes` as my `WHERE` clause does not include the primary key. However, I do not need to filter by primary key as I only care about entries who do not have a value for the new column.

The query I'm running is PartiQL is:

```
UPDATE <table-name>
SET <new-field>=0
WHERE NOT <new-field>=0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PartiQL `UPDATE` `WHERE` clause must identify a single DyanmoDB item.  As the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.update.html) say:

> You can only update one item at a time; you cannot issue a single DynamoDB PartiQL statement that updates multiple items. For information on updating multiple items, see Performing Transactions with PartiQL for DynamoDB or [Running Batch Operations with PartiQL for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.multiplestatements.batching.html).

What this means in practice is that you (1) `scan` for all the target records and (2) then issue a `UPDATE` statement for each record, ideally batched together.

Comment: Hey @fedonev, thanks for the reply! This means that there is no single query I can use to update me entire database correct?

In that case, I would have to perform a scan and update?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Updating multiple records is a two step process.